# Weird errors running a simple one step pipeline on a hosted Linux agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My pipeline has a single Powershell step with the following code:

```
$pat = ConvertTo-SecureString $env:System_AccessToken -AsPlainText -Force
$AzureDevOpsCredentialArg = @{ Credential = [Management.Automation.PSCredential]::New("user", $pat) }
$Uri = $env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI.Replace("/dev.azure.com/", "/pkgs.dev.azure.com/")
$Uri = "$Uri/_packaging/dayforce/nuget/v2"
Register-PSRepository -Name 'Dayforce-QA' -SourceLocation $Uri -PublishLocation $Uri -InstallationPolicy Trusted @AzureDevOpsCredentialArg
```

There is no other code in the pipeline. This is on the `ubuntu-latest` hosted agent. Here is the output:

```
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet--V does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet--V does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet--V does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet--V does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
```

It seems some code invokes `dotnet -V` several times. But it does not fail the step! It is still green. Nonetheless it bothers me and I want to eliminate the root cause for this output.

Here is the pipeline link - https://dev.azure.com/MarkKharitonov0271/Demo/_build/results?buildId=36&view=logs&j=ca395085-040a-526b-2ce8-bdc85f692774&t=319cc4f9-2fdf-5261-34c0-5e64584fddb0

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT 1**

I have rewritten it to use YAML. Also, added an extra step to show that `dotnet` command line exists and that `dotnet --version` returns 6.0.400, but `dotnet -V` produces exactly the same output as in the problematic step.

Right now the step also fails with an error that seems bogus to me as well. The URL it complains about seems totally valid.

Comment: This looks like a generic error when an [executable file is not found](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/troubleshoot-usage-issues#executable-file-not-found). I guess the way to fix this is to address the root cause —  see why the executable is not found.

Comment: From your logs: `[command]/usr/bin/pwsh -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command . '/home/vsts/work/_temp/fb618eaf-bc56-4c0c-87e9-7f865854f9dd.ps1' 

Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.`

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use YAML pipelines, not classic pipelines. Classic pipelines are effectively deprecated.

Comment: @DanielMann - Yes, I use only them, for this question I was lazy to populate the repo, but you are on point. I will fix it right now to make it easier for the folks to help me.

Comment: @DanielMann - I have revamped the pipeline. It is now YAML. For some reason it fails to register the PS repository with another bogus error.

Comment: @Nikhil - I have rewritten the pipeline as YAML. Also added a step to show that `dotnet` is present. The pipeline now fails at the end, not clear why. Another mystery.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a `powershell` alias on a non-Windows machine. Use `pwsh` instead.

> `powershell` runs Windows PowerShell and will only work on a Windows agent. `pwsh` runs PowerShell Core, which must be installed on the agent or container.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell

Comment: I am pretty sure the documentation is incorrect. I added a `powershell` step that outputs the version info - https://dev.azure.com/MarkKharitonov0271/Demo/_build/results?buildId=37&view=logs&j=ca395085-040a-526b-2ce8-bdc85f692774&t=50b9345f-2a7f-5980-cb0f-1a8f9fb09dd0&l=32. It is pretty much PS.Core running on Linux. I do not think it has anything to do with my problem.